# Dishwasher Drain Pump - Need Help!

Tags: dishwasher

My whirlpool WDT710PAYM6 dishwasher stopped draining. I checked the ohms on the drain pump and they were out of spec with the service manual (way too low). So I bought a new drain pump, but that didn't help. So I bought a new control board, but that didn't help either.

Oddly, it seems that I'm getting voltage to the pump at the correct time - if I put the dishwasher on drain, I get 122v on one of the leads to the pump (I think the left one). I also checked the continuity of both the wires running to the pump, and they are both about 0.03 ohms.

When I say it doesn't drain, I mean the pump doesn't even try - there's no humming, buzzing or noise of any sort. I've even tried it with the pump out, but I get no action. Am I missing something obvious? There are no blockages in the drain hose, air gap issues, and no debris in the impeller. My dishwasher doesn't even have a drain valve/solenoid, so it seems this can't be such a brain scratcher!

Comment: Maybe the little float thingy that tells the computer when there is water in the machine is stuck or kaput.

Comment: I'll test it, but the dishwasher isn't overfilling with water, and also that wouldn't explain why the pump is getting voltage but still not working.

Comment: when testing the voltage to the drain pump, should I be getting 120v across the two wires that plug into the pump? I only pick up volts on one wire when testing against ground. The other one is nothing.

Comment: You should measure 120V across that pair of wires. You'll need to diagnose why one of them is floating.